# Keeping CSV format in string when inserting into xls with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I am very stuck at the last part of my code which is displaying all the raw data I get my results and calculations from. I want the data to be displayed like it is in the csv file as shown below however currently is shown like so. Does anyone know how to fix this?

(using python and openpyxl)

[This is how I want the data to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyxlH.png)

[This is how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVmZB.png)

Here is my code so far.

```
raw_data = []

for value in match:
    with open(path + value, newline='') as File:
        raw_data.append(value)
        for row in File:
            if "Delta Response" in row:
                raw_data.append(row)
            if "Channel Response" in row:
                raw_data.append(row)
line=1 
for p in raw_data:
    print(p)
    sheet2.cell(row=line, column=1, value=p)
```

Comment: This code is incomplete and it is not clear what the variables refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in your `for value in match:` you're iterating over rows, and adding those rows to the `raw_data` array, and then in `for p in raw_data:` you're iterating over those rows, and adding them in the sheet with `column=1`, so it's forcing all of the row into the first column. I don't know what library the `cell` command is from, but maybe you should be using a `row` function instead, or inside the `for p in raw_data:` you could try something like:

```
for column_var, cell_value in enumerate(p.split(',')):
    sheet2.cell(row=line, column=column_var, value=cell_value)
```